# What is the difference between .bash_profile and .bash_login?

Tags: bash

I've been researching about how bash works, and so far I've learned the following things:

When starting a login shell, the first of the following files that exists gets executed:

`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`

When starting a non-login shell (or a sub-shell) that is interactive, the `~/.bashrc` file gets executed.

Also, .profile gets executed by other shells like sh. My question now is, what is the point of having a .bash_profile as well as a .bash_login? They both perform the same functions, and unlike .profile, both .bash_profile and .bash_login are both only read by bash. The only difference that I know between them is that .bash_login gets executed if .bash_profile is not present. So why is it there?

Comment: There is really no point in it. It's a compatibility thing, it has always been that way (eg. back in [1996](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=726f63884db0132f01745f1fb4465e6621088ccf#n851)).

Comment: Compatibility with what though?

Comment: And how does having `~/.bash_login` help with that

Comment: I guess some people had their startup file named that way, and in those times randomly breaking people's configs was not yet considered a feature -- but why not ask Chet Ramey himself?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/2303098 "What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?")? Also, `.bash_login` is explained in the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html "bash(1)") as `"When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file  /etc/profile,  if  that  file exists. After  reading  that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order"`

Comment: @ckujau I understand the order, and what/how/when bash executes which files. What I wanted to know was why `~/.bash_login` exists at all. I mean, it functions exactly like `~/.bash_profile` in that only bash can read it, and it gets run when a login terminal is invoked. Other than the fact that `~/.bash_login` runs only if there is no `~/.bash_profile`, there seems to be no different than the two, and that difference is completely useless. Why make a `~/.bash_login` at all?

Answer (score 9):

The `csh` shell, from which `bash` got a few features, uses `.login` as the name of the shell startup file to run when starting a login shell, just like `ksh`, another shell that heavily influences the `bash` shell, uses `.profile` as the startup file for login shells.

Therefore, `.bash_profile` borrows its name from the `ksh` shell's `.profile` file, while `.bash_login` borrows its name from the `csh` shell's `.login` file.

The user uses `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` depending on from what other family of shells (`ksh`-like shells or `csh`-like shells) they are migrating to `bash` from.

Obviously, nowadays, many Linux users have never used another shell than `bash`, so whatever filename they use will more likely depend on the preferences of their system administrator, of their teacher, or it may be random chance.

If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` exists, then the `~/.bash_login` file will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage to using the optional script name **`~/.bash_login`**, *rather than `~/.profile`*, is that there is a parallel name for your logout script, **`~/.bash_logout`**, if you decide to use it.

So if you're running Bash, rather than Bourne, this simplifies the configuration name set complexity from this:

```
/etc/profile         # system login       script
~/.bash_profile      # user   login       script
~/.bash_logout       # user   logout      script

/etc/bash.bashrc     # system interactive script
       ~/.bashrc     # user   interactive script
```

---

to this:

```
/etc/profile         # system login       script
~/.bash_login        # user   login       script  <--sisters +
~/.bash_logout       # user   logout      script  <----------+

/etc/bash.bashrc     # system interactive script
       ~/.bashrc     # user   interactive script
```

---

However, if you don't intend to use a logout script, this other way might be simpler for you:

```
   /etc/profile      # system login       script
~/.bash_profile      # user   login       script

/etc/bash.bashrc     # system interactive script
       ~/.bashrc     # user   interactive script
```

---

**Too bad there isn't more name symmetry in the config names...**

But you might make this somewhat better with these symbolic links:

```
/etc/bash   -->    /etc/profile   # system login       script
  ~/.bash   --> ~/.bash_profile   # user   login       script

/etc/bashrc --> /etc/bash.bashrc  # system interactive script
  ~/.bashrc                       # user   interactive script
```

Non-destructively created with:

```
sudo ln -sT    /etc/profile  /etc/bash
     ln -sT ~/.bash_profile    ~/.bash

sudo ln -sT /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bashrc
#                              ~/.bashrc  (don't change)
```

**Or** you can get more aggressive and reverse this, and move the files to the new names, and instead back-link them:

```
sudo mv -f    /etc/profile       /etc/bash          && \
sudo ln -sT   /etc/bash          /etc/profile

sudo mv -f    /etc/bash.bashrc   /etc/bashrc        && \
sudo ln -sT   /etc/bashrc        /etc/bash.bashrc

     mv -f    ~/.bash_profile    ~/.bash            && \
     ln -sT   ~/.bash            ~/.bash_profile

#             ~/.bashrc              (don't change)
```

---

**Either way, now you have these more uniform config file names**, easily found when you forget them from their links:

```
/etc/bash    # system login       config script
  ~/.bash    # user   login       config script

/etc/bashrc  # system interactive config script
  ~/.bashrc  # user   interactive config script
```

(I don't use a logout script, but it would probably be named: `/etc/bash.logout` .)